# "emerge as something" or "emerge something"?

Tags: word-usage

Tell me please if  the word "emerge" was used correctly in the following sentence.

> "Oleksandr Usyk **emerged a serious danger** to world heavyweight titleholders Anthony Joshua and Deontay Wilder on Saturday." ([Source](http://www.espn.com/boxing/story/_/id/24163924/oleksandr-usyk-serious-danger-anthony-joshua-deontay-wilder))

Should not it be "he emerged **as** a serious danger"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either is acceptable:

emerged {something}

emerged as {something}

Among the results [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22emerged%20victor%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) you will find **emerged victor** for example.

> It was really admirable how he emerged victor in the end...
>
> ...he'd emerged victor in a general election...

Or this sentence which I've just made up:

> He emerged from the Florida primary a serious danger to the party's old guard.
>
> From the Florida primary he emerged a serious danger to the party's old guard.

P.S. Since the comments have been removed, I'll add a note here that **emerge** is intransitive and **a serious danger to the party's old guard** is a complement predicated of the subject, "he".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80658/discussion-on-answer-by-tomauo-emerge-as-something-or-emerge-something).

Answer (score 1):

It could be correct the way it is, depending on context.

Yes, it sounds a little smoother to say "emerged as X" to mean "came out of the situation as X", but it's also perfectly correct to say things like "He emerged from the spa a new man".

The *as*-less version used to be more common, but in the last 50 or so years, *emerged as* seems to have taken over as the more common structure:
[image]

Comment: That you used "emerged from the spa a new man" is uncanny, since I had not seen your answer before leaving my comment.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo  The collective unconscious at work!

Comment: Right: He emerged from the spa a new man. So, emerge is an action or transitive verb? He caused a new man to come out of the spa? Tell me, are there two men in the sentence, or one? Are you emerging new arguments from Ngram? I rest my case. ESPN is wrong.

Comment: yes, the red line goes up and  up. The blue line declines. And I wonder why that is? Because most book editors know the difference, I would posit.

Answer (score 1):

I only searched for `"he emerged a"` on Google, but if you change the pronoun, article, tense, or employ some other techniques you'll find even more results:

From *The New York Times*:

> - [*He **emerged a lieutenant** in 1945 and in October of that year was signed to a Montreal contract.*](http://archive.nytimes.com/www.nytimes.com/packages/html/sports/year_in_sports/04.10.html)
> - [*Six years later, he **emerged a monk**.*](https://www.nytimes.com/2014/12/14/opinion/sunday/arthur-c-brooks-abundance-without-attachment.html)
> - [*When he made his reappearance in the early 1980's, he **emerged a different player**.*](https://www.nytimes.com/1991/07/18/arts/pop-in-review-976691.html)
> - [*He entered the prison system a devout believer in communism; he **emerged a profoundly tolerant believer in humanist principles**.*](https://www.nytimes.com/1977/10/22/archives/books-of-the-times-inside-the-red-army.html)
> - [*About five minutes and 16 frenzied, desperate and comical strokes later, he **emerged a folk hero**.*](https://www.nytimes.com/2011/04/16/sports/16golf.html)
> - [*Indeed, it's as if he **emerged a full-blown automatist**.*](https://www.nytimes.com/1983/09/11/nyregion/trenton-west-coast-expressionism.html)
> - [*He took a chance, but he **emerged a winner**.*](https://www.nytimes.com/1986/11/06/garden/ralph-lauren-not-a-petticoat-to-be-seen.html)
> - [*Pascal Lamy of France strengthened his bid to take over as head of the World Trade Organization on Friday when he **emerged a clear first** in the latest round of soundings of members, diplomats said Friday, Reuters reported from Geneva.*](https://www.nytimes.com/2005/04/30/business/worldbusiness/us-trade-representative-is-confirmed-by-senate.html)
> - [*And yet he **emerged a winner**: Lipton tea sales in America soared.*](https://www.nytimes.com/1983/08/21/sports/no-headline-113759.html)
> - [*Playing in an IMP game in which teams were determined by lot, he **emerged a winner** thanks in part to the diagramed deal.*](https://www.nytimes.com/1986/10/20/nyregion/bridge-australian-makes-his-mark-in-a-visit-to-cavendish-club.html)

From *The Times*:

> - [*Despite his failure, he **emerged a hero** after leading his 27 men to safety, escaping over the frozen sea to Elephant Island before sailing almost 800 miles in an open boat with five others to find help.*](https://www.thetimes.co.uk/article/race-on-to-find-shackleton-s-wrecked-ship-the-endurance-58nqxfc5h)

From *The Washington Post*:

> - [*He was raised in an orphan asylum and by foster parents -- sometimes a stranger in his own house -- yet he **emerged a loving man**, a man of such sound ethical principles that he sometimes seems to be a rebuke from a simpler age.*](https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/opinions/1998/12/24/goodness-in-a-ruthless-world/35e658fc-789e-47da-97c5-55b4b8b32c53/)
> - [*He **emerged a different pitcher**.*](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/nationals-journal/wp/2018/06/14/unemployed-in-august-justin-miller-has-been-mlbs-best-reliever-with-the-nationals/?utm_term=.d3aa89a50227)

Judging from this, I'd say it's not ungrammatical to dispense with the usual *as*, such as in *He emerged <s>as</s> a different pitcher*.

---

In the above sentences, *emerge* is a so-called **complex-intransitive** verb taking a **subject-oriented predicative complement**.

Examples of other verbs that take predicative complements (from *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* by Huddleston, Pullum, et al. (2002)):

> 1. Her son remained a danger.
> 2. That seems a good idea.
> 3. Pat proved a great asset.
> 4. He became our main ally.

The crucial property of predicative complement is that it can have the form of a bare noun phrase:

> 5. Finally, the human will emerge **winner**. ([source](https://m.sfgate.com/opinion/letterstoeditor/article/LETTERS-TO-THE-EDITOR-2840545.php))
> 6. In the battle scenes, no one emerges **victor** and the carnage applies to both sides. (source: [this article](https://www.questia.com/read/1G1-10412359/historian-with-a-brush), but only a small preview is available without a subscription)
> 7. Supported by his paper, corroborated by reporters on other papers, last week he emerged **hero of the occasion**. ([source (1928)](http://content.time.com/time/magazine/article/0,9171,928289,00.html))

and an adjective phrase:

> 8. He emerged **unscathed**, she later learned. ([source](https://www.nytimes.com/2009/08/17/us/17women.html))
> 9. At the Crisis Text Line, pleas for help more than doubled in the 24 hours since Trump emerged **victorious**. ([source](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/morning-mix/wp/2016/11/10/at-suicide-hotlines-the-first-24-hours-of-trumps-america-have-been-full-of-fear/?utm_term=.2d56a98d2679))
> 10. And you'll be unsurprised to learn that Hulkster emerged **triumphant** in that bout and many others before he later turned into a bad guy. ([source](https://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=91432799&t=1532471787238))

For comparison, an object cannot have the form of a bare noun phrase or an adjective phrase:

> 11. <sup><sub>UNGRAMMATICAL</sub></sup>She took **car**.
> 12. <sup><sub>OK</sub></sup>She took **the car**.
> 13. <sup><sub>UNGRAMMATICAL</sub></sup>He read **careful**.

Now we know that *emerge* doesn't take an object there, but a predicative complement.

There are two other distinctive properties of predicative complements, such as that they cannot be the subject of the corresponding passive clauses, and another, essentially confined to the verb *be*.

Comment: Your methodology is flawed. You start with hits. I found tons of hits as well. Both ways. Click on the links in my answer. This is not a predicative complement because intransitive verbs cannot take those:  http://www.csun.edu/~sk36711/WWW2/engl302/sentencetypes.htm You have to start with the kind of verb it is. That is the only way to start the analysis. You can't say it is a bare noun phrase here after the fact. The verb governs usage. Not a grammatical category you plunk down on it.

Comment: @Lambie Yes, I started with hits because I wanted to show you that it's attested and used. I've quoted a vetted grammar source and I think I'm right. Complex-intransitive verbs do take complements. Even your lousy source says the following: "A nominal subject complement is also called a predicate nominative in some grammars. The term nominal means something that functions as a noun. The term nominative is useful for specifying the case of the complement, as we’ll see in a moment. E.g.: *Those men are brutes. Our office is becoming a jungle. My three sisters remained friends afterwards.*"

Comment: @Lambie That's in the section titled "*Be* or Another Linking Verb Followed by a Nominal Subject Complement". So they consider *remain* a linking verb (look at the example). I call it a complex-intransitive verb. What's your argument again? By the way, I didn't make any of the above up; I stared at the book titled *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* and studied it, and showed you what it says. You can look it up yourself, it starts from page 253, and the section that describes categories of complex-intransitive verbs starts from page 253.

Comment: @Lambie And second of all, your methodology is definitely flawed since it appears you don't know what the results you have found indicate; just because you have found examples with *as* (exemplifying usage **no one disputes**), and even if there's more of such examples, it **doesn't mean the verb cannot be used without it** (in fact, there are numerous examples showing just that, as you said). You said you revered *The New York Times*, so I showed you examples from that newspaper. What more proof do you want? (And, that last page should've read 263, sorry.)

Comment: Nice work. If I could add one more: _But he emerged a shy young man with few friends_ ([The Economist](https://www.economist.com/books-and-arts/2004/11/18/rum-cove-really)). Funny how all these well-respected publications keep getting it wrong over and over again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80666/discussion-between-userr2684291-and-lambie).

Answer (score -3):

He emerged as a serious danger to x.

not:

He emerged a serious danger to x.

> **People can write whatever they want, use whatever they want, speak in whatever way they like.** (I cannot stress this enough). That said,
>   if one chooses to analyse a phrase based on existing, canonical
>   linguistic tools, then would start with the verb **emerge.**

1) First, is the verb emerge a transitive or intransitive?

2) All dictionaries define emerge as **intransitive**. It cannot take a direct object.

3) Here is **confirmation from a grammarian** much beloved of many who swim in these waters:

> A construction similar to the existential, known as the presentational
>   clause, has dummy *there* as subject not of **be** but of an
>   intransitive verb such as **appear, emerge, follow,** or **remain**. 
>   (bolding and italicizing by the authors)
>
> **A Student’s Introduction to English Grammar**, page 251. Rodney Huddleston and Geoffrey K. Pullum

Please note, I cite the author above to show that he too says **emerge is intransitive.**

4) If a verb is intransitive, it cannot be passivized. That is, "He was emerged" is not allowed under this rule. Also, if a verb is intransitive, it does not "take a direct object".

5) examining **emerge as a [noun]** (intransitive) versus **emerge a [noun]** (transitive).

A)
- They emerged unscathed from the ordeal.

- They emerged victorious from the competition.

In the two cases above, the adjectives unscathed and victorious function as described below:

> (c) Function A major difference between verbs and adjectives is that
>   verbs function as predicator (head of a VP) in clause structure
>   whereas adjectives do not. In their predicative use, adjectives occur
>   not as predicator but **as complement to a verb such as be, become,
>   seem , etc.**: [...] We became sad. You seem appreciative. [same book
>   as above, page 116.)

emerge refers to a state or condition: to appear by coming out of something or out from behind something (Collins Dictionary, AmE usage:
fig. The president **emerged unscathed** from the scandal (= He came out of it with no damage to his reputation).

B) If one wants to test the waters of using "emerge a victor from x" or similar constructions **without as** + determiner + noun, one would have to recognize victor (i.e. noun) as a direct object. As we have seen above though, it cannot take a direct object, and **this shows itself to be logical if one tries to construct other examples based on emerge + determiner + noun.**

- He emerged the engine from the car. (Sounds silly)
- They emerged victors from the race. (I put this second one here so readers can maybe "feel" how that does not really work.)
- You can merge two "objects", for example, two sentences or companies. That said, you cannot emerge them.

6) Dictionaries follow this rule. When emerge refers to a noun, it is invariably followed by as: emerge as a leader, emerge as [other noun].

7) Online hits are online hits. They contain no linguistic analysis. Here are a bunch of them with as (there are just as many examples without as, as posted in another answer. However, either way, on their own, this proves nothing linguistically):

> He emerged as a formidable warlord. Forbes
>
> 2 Netflix has emerged as
>   a new buyer.
>
> The New York Times
>
> 3 He also emerged as a soloist.
>
> The
>   New York Times
>
> 4 China has emerged as a special bogeyman.
>
> The New
>   York Times  5 Ms. Kagan emerged as a leader. The New York Times
>
> 6 It
>   emerged as a hotspot. The Guardian  7 George has also emerged as a
>   leader. The Guardian - Sport
>
> 8 Instead they emerged as a conference
>   power. The New York Times - Sports
>
> 9 Tchaikovsky emerged as a
>   19th-century modernist. The New York Times - Arts
>
> 10 Wood's artistic
>   promise emerged as a child. The Guardian - Music [emerge as](https://ludwig.guru/s/emerged+as+a)

For example, in Merriam Webster dictionary above:

to rise from an obscure or inferior position or condition someone **must emerge as a leader**

Emerge is intransitive: They emerged as victors.

You cannot say "They emerged victors because emerge is intransitive." is you want to actually follow the logic of the language.

This usage is in all the dictionaries. Every single example for the idea of something emerging from something applied to humans contains: emerge as [x].

**Intransitive  verbs do not take direct objects.**

Conclusion: **Use what you like.** But if you want to follow the actual logic of the verb emerge, **emerge as** is in keeping with it.

The NGRAM in another answer here shows this to be true. **Emerge as** has a steadily rising line, emerge a [something] does not. **That is possibly because book editors are pretty well informed about these matters**.

And when one actually thinks about this, one would probably add **as** for any usage that is clearly: to emerge from a situation in a state or condition. It is, of course, possible to argue that all these hits (findings) without as actually imply as. I think that when one actually thinks about it, one adds **as** in one's mind.

- He emerged from the primary election **in** an exhausted state.
- He emerged exhaust**ed** from the primary election.
- He emerged a winner from the primary election. [I would add as].
- He emerged boat from the  lake. [not English usage at all.]

[This answer has been reconfigured due to the need to cite authoritative sources.]

Comment: RE: _If you have a noun that describes a person_... Yes, and the word _danger_ can do just that. From Oxford: **danger** (*n*.) a person or thing that is likely to cause harm or injury. In this case, the "danger" is the danger of capturing the titles from  Anthony Joshua and Deontay Wilder – in other words, their status as current champions is now endangered, because this up-and-coming fighter is showing so much promise. The rest of the article explains: _alarm bells [are] ringing for the elite heavyweights; he [Usyk] he is now a real threat for the heavyweight champions and contenders_.

Comment: @J.R. I am saying that: ***He emerged a serious danger to y*** is not grammatical. Even if: "He emerged victor" passes some people's test. The best would be: he emerged as a serious threat **as a** can be followed by anything.

Comment: It is unbelievable to me. I am following the dictionary. ***He emerged a new man*** would mean something really funny because emerge is ***intransitive***. You don't emerge something. My goodness. Look  up the word in a dictionary. I'm going to emerge a new man, just wait. [that is a joke, so you can perhaps understand my gist here.] If it were transitive, you could say: they emerged new men from the elections. But you can't.

Comment: You have to say: They emerged as new men from the elections. One cannot emerge a [thing]; one can merge, however, two things; One can only emerge as a [thing].

Comment: You should try reading more biographies; plenty of accomplished writers forgo the _as_. There are scores of examples, but I think this one suffices nicely: _George Eliot was born .. in Warwickshire, England. From the strict religious background of her unhappy childhood and adolescence, she emerged a freethinker_ ("Revelations: Diaries of Women", 2011).

Comment: Who am I to go against the the intransitive usage found in dictionaries? I call these usages you cite non-standard. Writers often overlook these details. Yet, if the verb is intransitive,  then, it would have to take as. https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/emerge emerge as v. emerge with. There is no "emerge" + a [something] and that goes for the other online dictionaries as well.

Comment: Posting sentences is not proof of anything. I can find tons of stuff on ngrams and on the internet. That does not ***prove*** anything at all. Clearly, it is: she emerged (as) a freethinker. Otherwise,what does to emerge, the transitive verb mean??

Comment: Lambie, you posted a comment about this answer on an answer I wrote to a meta question. I think the reason why there are downvotes on this answer is because it's just not correct. People say and write, "he emerged a leader" or "they emerged victors" all the time. It *might* be technically "ungrammatical", but what is grammatical is not fixed and unchanging. As soon as enough people start using a certain phrasing, then it becomes grammatical. So the assertion here that leaving at "as" is ungrammatical is false, hence the downvotes.

Comment: @ToddWilcox ESPN posted the original text. ESPN does not always have great English. Ergo, my argument, is linguistically correct. If you accept "They  emerged victors" to mean 'They emerged as victors", that has consequences re the transitivity of the verb emerge. And answer me this, why does no dictionary even have a single example of this usage: emerged as a victor or emerged victors? Why is that? That is: emerge plus a/an [x:noun) or emerge plus [plural noun]. If this were standard, it would be in the dictionary (or dictionaries).

Comment: Dictionaries are not the final arbiters of English grammar, so what is or is not contained in them is not necessarily relevant. Answer me this: If your answer is correct, why does it have so many downvotes? It has downvotes because many users of this site agree that it is not correct. I'm a native English speaker and I have seen the construction of "emerged a `<noun>`" many, many times in my life, and in English, it's all about *usage*. If a construction is used often, then it's correct, no matter what any books say.

Comment: I never said dictionaries are the final arbiter. But if every single one says emerge is intransitive, and I know how transitivity works, my argument sticks. Why don't the Times of London and the New York Times use it?? It can be argued that ESPN has crappy grammar... I, too, thought, I knew all about it before I began my research. Using emerge transitively has consequences that cannot be denied. Otherwise, one has to resort to saying "that's the way it is". Journalistic usage is not the same as "people say it". People can speak 100% as they choose to speak.

Comment: @Lambie See [my answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/174045/3395).

Comment: It's one thing to dismiss random internet hits from bloggers or discussion boards, but iwhen you continue to insist that dozens of accomplished writers are all wrong but you are right, well, I hope the learmers here are smart enough to know where to put their trust.

Comment: J.R. Please see my reconfigured answer. I never said any accomplished writers were "wrong", did I? If I did, I didn't mean to. People and writers can use whatever they damn well please.  I advised the OP to use "emerge as" and it turns out my instinct was right. It follows a canonical analysis. At least I tried to analyze it and not just post  hits. I even found H&P saying emerge is intransitive.

Comment: I think that all the snarky comments directed at me or my sources are mean spirited. I remember rather vividly one group of people calling my explanations misinformation. In my experience, figuring out how something works in language can be painful, and not everyone knows how to maintain their  composure when the going gets tough. If the point here is to provide a reasoned argument, I have striven to do that.

Comment: The Google Books Ngram Viewer results in the other answer aren't quite to be trusted due to a large number of false positives such as *emerged a few minutes later*. Despite that, there truly are many examples of *as*-less usage of the verb *emerge*: there's no point in denying it, otherwise it looks pointlessly prescriptive because people do use the verb that way. I agree that learners would do well to stick to using *as* because that's more common – my answer merely attempts to classify *as*-less *emerge*, and dispels the notion that *as*-less usage is wrong/incorrect/ungrammatical.